# Can't install anything with Terminal commands

Tags: command-line

[image: 1]

Whenever I attempt to install anything through terminal commands it tells me, `Sorry, user Matthew is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get install ...`. I've already used the main account and successfully added myself into the `sudo` group and my profile was made with administrative capabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We want to be as helpful as possible, but in order to do so, we need a little more information. Try taking a screen shot of the exact usage of your command and the error it gives you. Then, press the "Edit" link and append it to your question!

Comment: Please post the entry from your /etc/sudoers file for this user. It should look something like this: `%matthew   ALL=(ALL) ALL` or `%Matthew   ALL=(ALL) ALL` Also, keep in mind that linux is case sensitive unlike windows so if your username is `Matthew` and you have `%matthew` entered in the file, it will not work. Alternatively, if your username is `matthew` and you have `%Matthew` entered into the sudoers file it will also not work.

Comment: Additionally, use the `sudo visudo` command to edit this file if you edit it.

Comment: How would I go about doing anything you just said lol. I said in noob terms as this is my first time using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check whether the user `matthew` is listed in the group `sudo`. Be careful that `matthew` != `Matthew`. To do that type this command:

```
grep 'matthew' /etc/group
```

The output should be something like:

```
sudo:x:27:matthew
```

But if it doesn't then that means `matthew` is not a member of the group `sudo` and thus cannot execute commands with `root` privileges. Also because of that you cannot run anything `sudo` while still booted into your current session.

The workaround is to logout of your current session. Then in the welcome screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then type the `username` as `root` and enter your `password`. After you are logged in, type:

```
adduser matthew sudo
```

Next, reboot using command:

```
reboot
```

Hopefully, now, you would be able to use any `sudo` commands as `matthew`.

**EDIT**: To check for the package `libgluezilla` do this `apt-cache search libgluezilla`. The output should be something like:

```
libmono-webbrowser2.0-cil - Mono Web Browser library (for CLI 2.0)
libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil - Mono Web Browser library (for CLI 4.0)
```

Install the required version by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

It is recommended to install `libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil`.

Comment: I now have root access, however, I cannot seem to install libgluezilla, it says it's obsolete or whatever. Does anybody know anything similar to it that I can install instead?

Comment: @MatthewBeck - What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: If the answer solved your question then, please [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/726971/119531) by clicking on [the upvote arrow and then the tick below it](http://i.imgur.com/YN8AQkd.png?1).

Comment: @MatthewBeck - edited.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` before that?

Answer (score 0):

Default server setup of Ubuntu would ask you to create an ordinary non-root user for security purposes.

To install something, just use **sudo**.

Ex. **sudo apt-get install apache2**.

Comment: Sudo asks me for a password and then tells me i'm not allowed to execute etc. basically what I said in my OP. Not trying to sound ungrateful in that, just didn't want to type it all out again.

Comment: User Matthew should be part of the **sudo _group_**. Check with the command **groups Matthew**.